# Запись стартового пути для хранения картинок в бд WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

У меня была идея хранить путь в формате "System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Photo\photo.png" для обхождения проблемы относительного пути и иметь возможность таким образом выводить картинки, считывая такой путь в программе, однако не знаю, будет ли это работать?

Comment: И решение странное и проблема надуманная. Обычно хранят в в базе без указания базового каталога, а если у вас какая-то проблема - опишите именно её, посмотрим как решить. Вероятно, вам стоит почитать про [Path.Combine](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: А если попробовать?

Comment: @AK У меня в программе на данный момент есть возможность только просматривать содержимое базы данных, однако в будущем планирую сделать режим администратора с возможностью добавления новых записей (и также с помещением туда пути к картинке). В таком случае мне необходимо придумать универсальное решение, которое будет работать не только локально. Была также мысль хранить картинки в каком-нибудь облаке и просто помещать в базу данных URL-ссылку на эти картинки, но пока что не пробовал и не знаю, сработает ли это.

Comment: Вы не знаете, как будет выглядеть работа в облаке, поэтому у вас и затруднения с текущей задачей. Вот когда у вас появятся подробности того, как устроена работа в облаке -- тогда и сможете решить задачу. А пока вы решаете неизвестно что -- конечно будет трудно. Просто попробуйте всё. И сделайте демо-приложение для локального варианта и прототип для облачного. Просто попробуйте. И когда сделаете -- сразу поймёте, как вам сделать общий вариант из двух.

Comment: Идея хранить изменяемые данные (базу) в каталоге с программой — не лучшая. Во взрослой ситуации ваша программа будет в Program Files, и текущий юзер не будет иметь прав записи туда. Используйте AppData. Если же база у вас только для чтения, тогда окей, но зачем тогда база?